# Hierarchical Visitor Pattern Sample

Tags: c#, design-patterns, software-design

I have a xml sample structure like below

```
<ManagementPack ContentReadable="true" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Manifest>
<Identity>
  <ID></ID>
  <Version></Version>
</Identity>
<Name></Name>
<References>
 <Reference Alias="SC">
    <ID></ID>
    <Version></Version>
    <PublicKeyToken></PublicKeyToken>
  </Reference>   
</References>
</Manifest>
<TypeDefinitions>
<EntityTypes>
  <ClassTypes>
    <ClassType ID="" Base="" Accessibility="" Abstract="" Hosted="" Singleton="" />
  </ClassTypes>
<RelationshipTypes>
    <RelationshipType ID="" Accessibility="" Base="" Abstract="">
      <Source></Source>
      <Target></Target>
    </RelationshipType>
   </RelationshipTypes>
</EntityTypes>
  </TypeDefinitions>
  <Monitoring>
<Discoveries>
  <Discovery ID="" Enabled="" Target="" ConfirmDelivery="" Remotable="" Priority="">
    <Category>Discovery</Category>
    <DiscoveryTypes />
    <DataSource ID="" TypeID="">
      <RuleId></RuleId>
      <GroupInstanceId></GroupInstanceId>
      <MembershipRules>
        <MembershipRule>
          <MonitoringClass></MonitoringClass>
          <RelationshipClass></RelationshipClass>
        </MembershipRule>
      </MembershipRules>
    </DataSource>
  </Discovery>
 </Discoveries>
```

.... etc.
I am trying to generate this XML structure. It seems i can manage that with visitor pattern but since structure contains nodes, visitor patttern seems not enough. I stumbled upon hierarchical visitor at http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HierarchicalVisitorPattern but i could not manage to create a sample. My priority is reduce if-else or switch statements. So is there any sample implementation with C# about hierarchical visitor or simple explanation with complete sample?

Comment: Why visitor is not enough?

Comment: Because i need hierarchical navigation and need to know if parent has a child or not. With visitor i need to write many if-else, which i want to reduce or stay away.

Comment: What `if-else`s do you need beyond checking if the node has or not children?

Comment: This is only a simple example. As for my real problem, i believe hierachical pattern suits me well but i couldn't manage to write one.So i just need a sample code with given simple structure

Comment: This is vague and incomplete. Post what you already have, create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) if necessary.

Comment: changed question for being more descriptive